# Replacing table content using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to parse a HTML document which has tabular data also in it using beautiful soup. I am doing some NLP over it.

The table cells might have just numbers or might be text heavy. So before doing soup.get_text(), I wish to change the content of the tabular data as per the following condition.

Condition: If the cell has more than two words( we can consider a number to be one word), then only keep it, else change the cell contents to an empty string.

```
<code to change table data based on condition>

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = soup.get_text()
```

Here is something that I have tried.

```
    tables = soup.find_all('table')
    for table in tables:
        table_body = table.find('tbody')
        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            for ele in cols:
                if len(ele.text.split(' ')<3):
                    ele.text = ''
```

However, we can't set ele.text so it throws an error.

Here's a simple HTML Structure with Table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>HTML Tables</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <table border = "1">
         <tr>
            <td><p><span>Row 1, Column 1, This should be kept because it has more than two tokens</span></p></td>
            <td><p><span>not kept</span></p></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td><p><span>Row 2, Column 1, should be kept</span></p></td>
            <td><p><span>Row 2, Column 2, should be kept</span></p></td>
         </tr>
      </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you found the element then use `ele.string.replace_with("")`

Based on your sample html

```
html='''<html>

   <head>
      <title>HTML Tables</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <table border = "1">
         <tr>
            <td><p><span>Row 1, Column 1, This should be kept because it has more than two tokens</span></p></td>
            <td><p><span>not kept</span></p></td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td><p><span>Row 2, Column 1, should be kept</span></p></td>
            <td><p><span>Row 2, Column 2, should be kept</span></p></td>
         </tr>
      </table>

   </body>
</html>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
for table in tables:
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        for ele in cols:
            if len(ele.text.split(' '))<3:
               ele.string.replace_with("")

print(soup)
```

**Output**:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td><p><span>Row 1, Column 1, This should be kept because it has more than two tokens</span></p></td>
<td><p><span></span></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p><span>Row 2, Column 1, should be kept</span></p></td>
<td><p><span>Row 2, Column 2, should be kept</span></p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```